# How to bitshift negative numbers with mySQL to get results like in Java, Python etc?

Tags: mysql, unsigned, signed

When i want to bitshift -2 >> 4 it should give me -1. python and java do give me -1. But if i try it on my mySQL server i get 1152921504606846975. I tryed to inverse the bits to cast it etc But i am not able to get a -1. So does someone know how to bitshift it to get -1.

Comment: *"When i want to bitshift -2 >> 4 it should give me -1. python and java do give me -1"* By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#bit-operations-complement-shift), MySQL's bit shift operators generate an *unsigned* 64-bit integer.  Therefore, if you want to get the expected behavior with negative numbers, you may add your own logic:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 4 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT -4
)

SELECT
    IF(val > 0, val >> 2, -1.0*((-1.0*val) >> 2)) AS result
FROM yourTable;
```

This outputs:

```
1
-1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

[>>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_right-shift):

> Shifts a longlong (BIGINT) number to the right.
>
> The result is an **unsigned 64-bit integer.** The value is truncated to 64 bits. In particular, if the shift count is greater or equal to the width of an unsigned 64-bit number, the result is zero.

`-1` does not belong to the range of unsigned integer.